# Cortana custom commands not installed onto windows 8.1 phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, windows, cortana, vcd

I am looking forward to make Cortana redirect custom commands to my app (Cortana API Integration).

Commands.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.1">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" >
    <CommandPrefix>Computer</CommandPrefix>
    <Example> who are the indians </Example>



    <Command Name="Origins">
      <Example> who are the indians </Example>
      <ListenFor> who are the {tribe} </ListenFor>
      <Feedback> looking for {tribe} </Feedback>
      <Navigate/>

    </Command>

    <PhraseTopic Label="tribe" Scenario="Tribe Info">
      <Subject>   Tribe </Subject>
    </PhraseTopic>

  </CommandSet>


</VoiceCommands>
```

Extract of App.xaml.cs

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                var storageFile =
           await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
               new Uri("ms-appx:///Commands.xml"));
                await Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.VoiceCommandManager.InstallCommandSetsFromStorageFileAsync(storageFile);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed");
                MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Problem chief.");
                msg.ShowAsync();
                //throw;
            }
}
```

I have also turned on Microphone capabilities in the manifest file. I am running VS 2015, and debug it directly onto my device lumia 525 which runs windows 8.1.
The app installs normally (and since I haven't added any UI part it shows a simple black screen) doesn't crash and the debug doesn't show anything unusual.

```
'App6.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App6.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'D:\WPSystem\APPREPOSITORY\d8c976b1-9b9b-47a3-8b2c-8f6dc74eeee5_1.0.0.0_neutral__2f5008nxamf4t\NI\App6.ni.EXE'. Symbols loaded.
'App6.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App6.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App6.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App6.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0xf44 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The Cortana doesn't feature my command in "What can I say?" list nor does it respond to the commands.